# how can i open my activity similar to alert dialog box if i click any listView Item?

Tags: javascript, android, listview, android-alertdialog

I am newbie. I am having one list view, If i click any item from the list it should open an alert dialog box which has some instruction to feed, as it has so many buttons, spinner, edit text etc. so i decided to make it as activity.

As of now i made xml file just to check whether it will work or not & after that i will do its coding. Now my question is how can make it as alertdialog box and opens when items click in list view.

Here is my SubMenu Activity :

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long rowId) {
        final AlertDialog customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();
        final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup
                , null);
        customDialog.setView(dialogView);
        // set the custom customDialogimation components - text, image and button
        final TextView tvDistance = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.h2);


        final Button okbtn=(Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ok) ;
        okbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                customDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        final Button cnclbtn=(Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.canc) ;

        cnclbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                customDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
    }
    }
```

I tried using popup as u can see above but thts not working if u click or choose any button etc.

Here is my mydialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/desimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/h1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Chicken Pizza Small"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/h2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Chicken Pizza Small Combo"
            android:textColor="#8c8181"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/quant"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@drawable/mybtn"
                android:text="Quantity"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:background="@drawable/stroke_button"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/incr"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:background="@color/colorwhite"
                    android:textColor="#FFA726"
                    android:textSize="25dp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:text="5" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/colorwhite"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textColor="#FFA726"
                    android:textSize="25dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/sl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="#c0c0c0"
                android:text="SL"
                android:textColor="#8c8181"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/s"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="#c0c0c0"
                android:text="S"
                android:textColor="#8c8181"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/m"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="#c0c0c0"
                android:text="M"
                android:textColor="#8c8181"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/L"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="#c0c0c0"
                android:text="l"
                android:textColor="#8c8181"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/f"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="#c0c0c0"
                android:text="F"
                android:textColor="#8c8181"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/stroke_button"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/stroke_button"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke_button"
            android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin1">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:lines="5"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textColor="#c0c0c0" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/canc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton2"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ok"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybtn"
                android:text="Ok"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want this to appear as a dialog when u click any listview Item. kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AlertDialog` for showing your custom layout as a dialog. Use below code to have the result:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long rowId) {
    final AlertDialog customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubMenu.this).create();
            final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mydialog, null);
            customDialog.setView(dialogView);
            // set the custom customDialogimation components - text, image and button
            final TextView tvDistance = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.h2);
 customDialog.show();
    }
```

to refer any component of your dialog layout always use `dialogView.findViewById`. You can write all component actions through this.

Comment: i am getting  red line on getActivity()

Comment: yes ,its working...but can i do all coding here in dialog box ,because here i will have to call images from server ,the image which is shown there is just demo image ,,can i do that in this dialog only

Comment: but its not canceling ??

Comment: Yes, you can. Just create an Asynctask. On post execute of asynctask show the dialog.

Comment: first of all thx fr ur help..now i want to make those two button ince or decr through coding

Comment: If yes, then onClickListener of this two button, write this line: customDialog.dismiss();

Comment: if i do that dialog is nt appearing

Comment: Yes. Its perfect.

Comment: yupp...going to post another questions for inc and decr button:)

Comment: hi sneha ..need ur help

Comment: plz see here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340634/how-can-i-make-spinner-inside-alert-dialog-box-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Put your scroll view inside a FrameLayout and than make the second child some sort of Layout (let's say RelativeLayout)that goes on top of the scroll view
the frame layout will put the second child in front of the first one by default , make the second child visibility:gone and when there is a click in the listview make him visible , make his size match parent and add margin so you can see what's behind.

**Example :**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    ...
    ...
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"></RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can show `AlertDialog` in listview item click.. you have to override your onItemClick method

```
  @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long rowId) {


        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                SubMenu.this);
                alert.setTitle("List");
                alert.setMessage(" selected Item is="
                +parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
               .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                        // do whatever you want to do
                    }
                }).show(); 

   }
```

Answer (score -1):

making an activity is not quite a good idea i think. Would you try custom `AlertDialog` ? You can check out this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

In your custom `alertDialog` you can use your own layout. Trust me I worked as instructed and it worked!

Comment: ok but in alert ther will b spinner,chbox etc all,,will it work on dialog properly?

Comment: yes obviously, you just make the layout, inflate the Layout using `LayoutInflater` as instructed, write necessary methods in your `AlertDialogBuilder` and you are good to go.